# How to redirect to a new page only when the last modal is closed

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a series of modals that are triggered based on the `div` `class`.

In the example below the modals are triggered when 2 `div` have a specific `class`. So when 2 cards match.

I would like to add a page redirect after **ALL** the `divs` have class ****.matched**** but **only** when the last modal is closed

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gj162fpo/2/)

Comment: Your last 4 questions were all about the same project, step by step, for which you have absolutely tried nothing, just keep building on the answers you receive. You should try something yourself. Don't you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check whether all the divs contain the class with every close button click and reload/redirect once they do.

```
const closeButton = document.querySelector('.clsBtn')
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.flip')
closeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let matched = true
    cards.forEach(card => {
        if (!card.classList.contains('matched')) {
            matched = false
        }
    })
    if (matched === true) {
        location.reload();
    }
})
```

Need to add a class to the close button.

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary clsBtn" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```